# How to render a jQuery AJAX JSON object from PHP to KnockoutJS

Tags: php, ajax, json, knockout.js

Wondering if anyone can do a quick demo on Jsfiddle to show how it would work to do the following.

Let's say I have a mysql table with columns: product_name, product_price, product_id;
I do a mysql select and return the array using an AJAX call. How do I render that on page using Knockout?

I can do the AJAX call and grab the data. It's returned as an object. I use json_encode in the PHP to return the data back in getJSON call.

What do I do next to render it? That's what I am stuck on. I just want to render a table looping product name, product id, and price.

```
    var allData = $.getJSON("ajax.php?request=getresults", data, function(response) {
        return (response);
    })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. I found an example and it works! [loading a knockout.js observableArray() from .ajax() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730496/loading-a-knockout-js-observablearray-from-ajax-call)

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/EYueU/